# Sync <select> by <option> location

Tags: javascript, html-select

I can only select the next synchronization is complete by the onchange event,like "mySelect" sync "mySelect1" ,  "mySelect1" sync "mySelect2" , "mySelect2" sync "mySelect3"

```html
   <form>

<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" onchange="mySelect1.options[selectedIndex].selected=true">
<option value="qww">qww</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="12w">12w</option>
<option value="wq">wq</option>
</select>
<select name="mSelect1" id="mySelect1" onchange="mySelect2.options[selectedIndex].selected=true" >
<option value="1s">1s</option>
<option value="22s">22s</option>
<option value="wz">wz</option>
<option value="wzz">wzz</option>
</select>
<select name="mSelect2" id="mySelect2" onchange="mySelect3.options[selectedIndex].selected=true">
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="dddw">dddw</option>
<option value="xc">xc</option>
<option value="zz">zz</option>

</select>
<select name="mSelect3" id="mySelect3" >
<option value="ddd">ddd</option>
<option value="ddxw">ddxw</option>
<option value="xxc">xxc</option>
<option value="zxz">zxz</option>

</select>
</form>
```

but I think by choosing the first select, so that the value of all select the same position behind all the show. You can do that?

just like this,When I selected the "mySelect" the "12", then  "mySelect1" of "22s",  "mySelect2" of "dddw", "mySelect3" the "ddxw" simultaneously selected,as of  Are the same position

Answer (score 1):

Code off the top of my head, should do the job though

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var targetIndex=$(this).prop("selectedIndex")
    $("select").each(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).find("option:eq("+targetIndex+")").val());
    });
});
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/uvmt0wos/

Comment: You can just use .index().

Comment: Well, I did not know that function existed, hold up will update code.  Thanks for the info

Comment: .index() as it turns out is not designed for this use case, but I found the property `selectedIndex` works very well.  Answer has been updated accordingly